# How to increase Python optimization speed while solving for multiple variables

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am trying to obtain values for 24 variables while solving a static simulation.  Each variable represents lengths of 24 wires, and I am trying to obtain a pre-set tension on the wire through this optimization. Changing the length of one wire affects tension in all other wires.

Currently I am using the minimize function with Nelder-Mead method from scipy.optimize module. My objective function is the sum of absolute difference between pre-set tension and achieved tension values (calculated in objfn using a commercial software).

Even after 3000 iterations, the solver is unable to find a close enough solution. Any suggestion about what optimization method should be used when these many variables are involved and they needs to be varied by ±5 with precision of 0.01.

```
import OrcFxAPI
import os
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy.optimize import minimize

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
fileName = 'Jetty_Mooring.dat'
model = OrcFxAPI.Model(fileName)


# Target Pretension Values
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
target_pretensions = {'Line1': 91.0,'Line2': 91.0,'Line3': 91.0,'Line4': 49.0,
                      'Line5': 49.0,'Line6': 49.0,'Line7': 59.0,'Line8': 60.0,
                      'Line9': 60.0,'Line10': 68.0,'Line11': 68.0,'Line12': 68.0,
                      'Line13': 57.0,'Line14': 57.0,'Line15': 57.0, 'Line16': 55.0,
                      'Line17': 55.0,'Line18': 54.0,'Line19': 48.0, 'Line20': 48.0,
                      'Line21': 48.0,'Line22': 89.0,'Line23': 88.0, 'Line24': 89.0,
                      'Fender 1': - 200.0,'Fender 2': - 202.0, 
                      'Fender 3': - 206.0, 'Fender 4': - 207.0}

def objfn(wire_lengths):


    for i in range(24):
        line = model['Line' + str(i+1)]
        line.Length[0] = wire_lengths[i]

    try:
        model.CalculateStatics()


        # difference between targe and achieved pretension
        diff = 0
        achieved_pretension = {}
        for i in range(24):
            line = model['Line' + str(i+1)]
            pretension = line.StaticResult('Effective Tension', OrcFxAPI.oeEndA)
            achieved_pretension['Line' + str(i+1)] = pretension
            diff = diff + abs(target_pretensions['Line' + str(i+1)] 
                                    - achieved_pretension['Line' + str(i+1)])

        for i in range(4):
            fender = model['Fender ' + str(i+1)]
            pretension = fender.StaticResult('Tension')
            achieved_pretension['Fender '+ str(i+1)] = pretension
            diff = diff + abs(target_pretensions['Fender ' + str(i+1)] 
                                    - achieved_pretension['Fender ' + str(i+1)])

    except:
        print('OrcaFlex Static calculation not converged.')
        #input('>')
        return 1E8  # Returning a very large number in case of error

    return diff

# Initial condition
x0 = {'Line1': 48.3089,'Line2': 46.7486,'Line3': 45.6178,
                       'Line4': 10.2308,'Line5': 8.0667,'Line6': 6.8685,
                       'Line7': 46.6303,'Line8': 48.7554,'Line9': 50.5218,
                       'Line10': 33.3988,'Line11': 31.5107,'Line12': 29.5331,
                       'Line13': 31.9916,'Line14': 34.0526,'Line15': 35.8218, 
                       'Line16': 48.4918,'Line17': 46.8255,'Line18': 44.8937,
                       'Line19': 8.5358, 'Line20': 8.3543, 'Line21': 8.9467,
                       'Line22': 44.2500,'Line23': 45.7275, 'Line24': 47.50}
x0=list(x0.values())

# Nelder-Mead
result = minimize(objfn, x0, method = 'Nelder-Mead', options = {'disp': True,'ftol':0.001,'eps':0.1})


print(result)
```

EDIT: Since a lot of the commenters wanted to see the Objective function, I have added the whole code here. Please note, that a software OrcaFlex is required to run the model `Jetty_Mooring.dat` to obtain results used in the Objective function. However, this should give some understanding of the problem.

Comment: "The Nealder-Mead algorithm is meant to be used for low-dimensionality problems."  6 is suggested maximum, maybe 8 (from answers at: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/129747-what-is-the-maximum-number-of-variables-for-practical-use-of-fminsearch?)

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for a suitable method pertaining to my problem?

Comment: Try the other optimizers. But without you showing objfn it's guess-work

Comment: @sascha: The objective function is sum of abs(target_tension - achieved_tension). The tension values are obtained by solving a static analysis using a software OrcaFlex. You can see the full description of the problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598954/how-to-set-optimization-variable-resolution-in-scipy-optimize-minimize

Comment: Did it not occur to you, that your kind of problem-description is incomplete when there is no reaction to your other question and here people are struggling too? ```target_tension``` could be everything, same for ```achieved_tension```. Probably at least one is non-constant. But who knows...

Comment: The `target_tension` values are constants. The length of the wires are varied to reach these tension values. The `achieved_tension` values are obtained for each iteration of the optimization by running a software. The optimizer is failing to converge to a solution because the number of variables (24) is too large . If I set the initial condition very close to the solution, then the optimizer is successful. However, setting a perfect initial condition is not possible all the time, hence looking for a robust solution.

Comment: Without knowing the actual objective function it is quite hard to suggest a well suitable one. Why don't you just try out the minimizers implemented in [scipy.optimize.minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html)? It's not that many after all.

Comment: Thank you @obachtos. I did try out a number of optimizers available under the minimize function(both bounded and non-bounded). I have edited the question with full code including the objective function. I have also reached out to the software company for help, and found that they have an optimizer built into the software to do the same task. Tried the same, and found it to require similar accuracy for initial condition. I believe I need to look for multi objective solvers now.